# Describe all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb R[t] /\langle t^4+t^3-3t-3, t^6-9\rangle$ to $\mathbb C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Describe all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb R[t] /\langle t^4+t^3-3t-3, t^6-9\rangle$ to $\mathbb C$.

What determines the homomorphisms? This seems quite confusing. Any general explanation on how to solve this type of problems would be much appriciated!

Comment: You should recall that $\Bbb{R}[t]$ is a principal ideal domain. Indeed, it helps if you first find a single generator for that ideal. Do you remember how that is done?

Comment: Yes, finding the gcd of the two polynomials. It's $<t^3-3>$.

Comment: Secondly, here it is moral certainty that you can assume that $\Bbb{R}$ to maps to itself, i.e. the real axis (the other homomorphism are too scary to be considered). After that the question becomes: where do you map $t$? Observe that both $t^6-9$ and $t^4+t^3-3t-5$ need to go to zero, because they are in the zero element of the quotient ring.

Comment: I wrote it incorrectly, should've been $t^4+t^3-3t-3$

Comment: Ok. $t^3-3$ is, indeed, the gcd.

Comment: Assuming that the real numbers go where you expect them to, are you familiar with the result that any ring homomorphism $f$ from $\Bbb{R}[t]$ to $\Bbb{C}$ is of the form $f(p)=p(z)$ for some fixed complex number $z$? What constrains the choice of $z$, when you know that the polynomials in the ideal $\langle t^3-3\rangle$ need to be mapped to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $K$ is a commutative ring and $f_1,\dotsc,f_n \in K[x]$, then $K$-algebra homomorphisms $K[x]/(f_1,\dotsc,f_n) \to A$ correspond to elements $a \in A$ such that $f_1(a)=\dotsc=f_n(a)=0$.

As remarked by Jyrki, your task is probably to determine the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphisms (not all ring homomorphisms).

Thus, you only have to solve the equation system $t^4+t^3-3t-3=t^6-9=0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Technically you can compose the embedding $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{C}$ with any of the uncountably many automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$. I think that the problem setter forgot about this possibility (by asking for ring homomorphisms as opposed to homomorphisms of $\Bbb{R}$-algebras), for otherwise I nominate them for the "cruel algebra teacher of the year" -award.

Comment: Does that mean that there is a homomorphism to a field iff there exists $a$ and that field which is a root?